# C runtime error with for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, runtime

I wrote a small snippit of code that I thought would work, and I am getting all the values displayed in the console but shortly thereafter I am getting an runtime error.  Anyone have any idea why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[10];

void main() {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    array[i] = i;    
    printf("%i", array[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
Runtime error   time: 0 memory: 2248 signal:-1
0123456789
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: change to `int main()` and `return 0;` , perhaps your OS does not cope with the missing return value

Comment: What is the compiler and OS?

Comment: The definition of `main` should certainly be changed to `int main(void)`, but I've never seen an implementation in which `void main()` would cause a runtime error. Did changing the definition to the more correct `int main(void)` actually correct the problem? It's important to know what compiler and OS you're using.

Comment: The lack of a `'\n'` at the end of the output can also, in principle, cause undefined behavior. It's not likely to be the cause of the symptom your'e seeing, but you should add something like `putchar('\n');` to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare function main as

```
int main()
```

and either remove statement `return;` or substitute it for `return 0;`

Declaring function main as void and using return statement without an expression results in undefined behaviour of the program.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know which compiler you are using. Since most the cases it depends on the compiler and OS behaviour. Different compiler provide different behaviour

## Miscrosoft Compiler

In case using Microsoft Compiler then it will not show any Warning Message while compiling. Thus some times developer doesn't know what the reason of things. In your case the same thing is happening you either don't use return statement or if you want to use return then use change the things as provided by Vlad. Full function would be like this

## Gcc Compiler

In case you are using GCC it will generate Warning Message as the default valid type under GCC is int main and return 0; in the end.

### using void

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[10];

void main(void) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       array[i] = i;    
       printf("%i", array[i]);
    }
 }
```

### using int

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[10];

int main(void) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       array[i] = i;    
       printf("%i", array[i]);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

## Another Example of using void with return

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[10];

void main(void) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       array[i] = i;    
       printf("%i", array[i]);
       if (i == 9) then return;
    }
}
```

The above example will not generate error as the function doesn't reached the loop ending and you have returned before. Thus, here no memory access voilation would not be generated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code that *could* in principle cause some kind of run-time error, but there's nothing that I'd *expect* to cause such an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[10];

void main() {
```

As others have mentioned, this is not one of the standard ways to define the `main` function. For your purposes, since you're not using command-line arguments, the correct definition would be:

```
int main(void) {
```

The C standard (1990, 1999, and 2011 editions) does permit a a hosted implementation to permit other forms for `main`; for example, Microsoft's compiler specifically permits `void main(void)` (and `void main()` would probably be acceptable as well). But there is no good reason to define `main` with a return type of `void`, since `int main(void)` is *guaranteed* to be correct.

If you define `main` using something other than one of the two standard forms (the other is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` *or* in a manner that your implementation documents, then your program's behavior is undefined.

On the other hand, the worst consequence I've seen for using `void main()` is a compile-time warning -- and the standard doesn't even require that. A compiler that accepts `void main()` without complaint and then generates code that causes a run-time error has, I would say, a serious bug, though it wouldn't actually violate the C standard. I'd be surprised if this were the cause of the error you're seeing.

```
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        array[i] = i;    
        printf("%i", array[i]);
```

This is perfectly ok; it should print `0123456789`. Printing multiple `int` values with nothing separating them is a bit odd, but it's not an error as such. (`"%i"` is equivalent to `"%d"`, and `"%d"` is more common.)

But your output is not terminated by a newline. On many systems, the output will just be printed without an end-of-line marker, which might mess up your terminal display. On others, the trailing newline might be required, and failing to provide one causes undefined behavior. (You don't need a newline on *all* your output, just at the very end.)

```
    }
```

I'd add something like

```
putchar('\n');
```

here, just to be sure.

```
    return;
```

A `return;` with no expression is perfectly valid in a `void` function -- though it's unnecessary at the very end of the function, since reaching the closing `}` does an implicit `return` anyway. But if you define `main` *correctly* as `int main(void)`, then this should be `return 0;`. Starting in C99, reaching the closing `}` of `main` is equivalent to executing a `return 0;`, so it's not strictly necessary -- but there are still compilers that don't fully support C99 (much less C11), so the adding the `return 0;` isn't a bad idea.

```
}
```

Here's a version of your program that corrects these issues, and *should* be 100% portable to all conforming hosted C implementations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[10];

int main(void) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        array[i] = i;    
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is:

```
0123456789
```

Try this and see if it corrects the run-time error. If it does, try starting with your original program and changing just one thing at a time (the definition of `main` along with the `return` statement, and the trailing newline) to see exactly what it is that corrects the problem.

It would be *very* helpful to know what compiler and operating system you're using.

(I've mentioned "hosted implementations". The other kind of C implementation is "freestanding"; it refers to implementations for embedded systems, where code may run directly on the hardware with no operating system. On such a system, most of the standard library is optional, and the correct definition of the program entry point is entirely implementation-defined; it might not even be called `main`. You're probably not using such an implementation.)