# C Recursion runtime error

Tags: c, arrays, function, recursion

I have this code which find longest nondecreasing sequence in array and print length of this sequence:

```
int max = 0;

void sequence(int *array, int start, int end, int last, int count)
{
   int i;
   if (start >= end)
   {
       if (count > max) max = count;
   }
   else
       for (i = start; i < end; i++)
       {
            if (array[i] >= last)
                sequence(array, i + 1, end, array[i], count + 1);
            else 
                if (i == end - 1 && array[i] < last)
                    sequence(array, i + 1, end, 0, count);
        }
}

void main()
{
    int x[] = { 1, 2 };
    sequence(x, 0, 2, 0, 0);
    printf("%d", max);
}
```

Everything is OK in my Visual Studio, but Ideone print **Runtime error time: 0 memory: 2160 signal:-1**

Comment: Possibly because you declared `main` wrong. It should return an `int`.

Comment: The program in that ideone link does not show any runtime error. At least when I just looked at it.

Comment: You have a recursive function. Please examine very carefully the conditions which causes it blows up the computer, and ensure you have conditions which end the recursion.

Comment: @AntoineMathys I think his function will have at most N^2 levels of recursion. Since `N=2`, that shouldn't cause an overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's already said, the reason is your `main` declaration.

The returned value of `main` indicates the exit code of program. The right declaration is

```
int main()
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

The declaration like

```
void main()
```

is mistaken but it's ignored by **C** (such declaration is prohibited in **C++**). In this case the returned value is unspecified.

You can read more there:

[What should main return in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

[Discussion on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-use-void-main-or-what-is-its-significance-in-C-programming)

This problem is looks like yours:

[Similar problem discussed on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048013/c-runtime-error-with-for-loop)

Also I tested Ideone a little and it seems that any **C** program with `void main()` get Runtime Error on Ideone.